# Outputting for loop iteration results to a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, append

I have a dataframe containing rows of scientific papers and each column is a different biological variable extracted from that paper. I want to do a pairwise analysis comparing two papers at a time and output the effect sizes to a new column in the dataframe for every pair. Therefore, I created a matrix containing different combinations of pairs and assigned the chosen pair to two papers in my dataframe. For every pair, i want R to see if my conditions are met and if they are then extract the chosen variables that i need to calculate my effect size and append the results back onto my original dataframe.

However i am just getting back errors OR it is only outputting the final effect size to every row of my dataframe.

```
pairs = t(combn(nrow(data), m = 2))

for (i in nrow(pairs)) {

  #Assignment of variables, comparing every condition to 'Conventional'
  a <- pairs[i,1]
  b <- pairs[i,2]
  paperone <- data[a,]
  papertwo <- data[b,]

  if (paperone$Management == "Conventional"){
    n1i <- paperone$n1i
    m1i <- paperone$m1i
    sd1i <- paperone$sd1i
  }

  if (papertwo$Management != "Conventional"){
    n2i <- papertwo$n1i
    m2i <- papertwo$m1i
    sd2i <- papertwo$sd1i
  }

  #Calculating effect sizes with assigned variables
  output <- escalc(measure="ROM", 
               n1i=n1i,
               n2i=n2i,
               m1i=m1i,
               m2i=m2i,
               sd1i=sd1i,
               sd2i=sd2i,
               var.names=c("LRR", "LRR_var"))

  data$LRR <- rbind(data, output$LRR)
  data$LRR_var <- rbind(data, output$LRR_var)
}
```

Comment: There is a lot going on in the loop. Often when debugging loops I let it run until it errors, then type `i` into the console to see which iteration caused the problem, then run *inside* the loop to see precisely which line of code caused the problem. Also, the last two lines inside the loop look suspicious; looks like you're assigning data.frames to a list item (but overriding it each loop iteration).

Comment: As well, you can--and should--eliminate the for loop entirely. Construct a function which works on one row of data. Then feed that function into each row with map() (or other relevant list processing fn)